# How can I do a stack trace using grep and regex?

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, regular-expression

I have a stack trace like this:

```
17/04/26 15:29:03 INFO HttpMethodDirector: Retrying request
17/04/26 15:29:03 ERROR NetworkClient: Node [192.168.5.5:9200] failed (Connection refused (Connection refused)); no other nodes left - aborting...
17/04/26 15:29:03 INFO HttpMethodDirector: I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused (Connection refused)
17/04/26 15:29:03 INFO HttpMethodDirector: Retrying request
17/04/26 15:29:03 ERROR NetworkClient: Node [192.168.5.5:9200] failed (Connection refused (Connection refused)); no other nodes left - aborting...
17/04/26 15:29:03 ERROR NetworkClient: Node [192.168.5.5:9200] failed (Connection refused (Connection refused)); no other nodes left - aborting...
17/04/26 15:29:03 INFO JDBCRDD: closed connection
17/04/26 15:29:03 INFO JDBCRDD: closed connection
17/04/26 15:29:03 INFO JDBCRDD: closed connection
17/04/26 15:29:03 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 4)
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Cannot detect ES version - typically this happens if the network/Elasticsearch cluster is not accessible or when targeting a WAN/Cloud instance without the proper setting 'es.nodes.wan.only'
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.InitializationUtils.discoverEsVersion(InitializationUtils.java:250)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestService.createWriter(RestService.java:546)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsRDDWriter.write(EsRDDWriter.scala:58)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.EsSparkSQL$$anonfun$saveToEs$1.apply(EsSparkSQL.scala:94)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.EsSparkSQL$$anonfun$saveToEs$1.apply(EsSparkSQL.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopNoNodesLeftException: Connection error (check network and/or proxy settings)- all nodes failed; tried [[192.168.5.5:9200]]
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.NetworkClient.execute(NetworkClient.java:150)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:444)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:424)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:428)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.get(RestClient.java:154)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.remoteEsVersion(RestClient.java:609)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.InitializationUtils.discoverEsVersion(InitializationUtils.java:243)
        ... 10 more
17/04/26 15:29:03 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 6)
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Cannot detect ES version - typically this happens if the network/Elasticsearch cluster is not accessible or when targeting a WAN/Cloud instance without the proper setting 'es.nodes.wan.only'
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.InitializationUtils.discoverEsVersion(InitializationUtils.java:250)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestService.createWriter(RestService.java:546)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsRDDWriter.write(EsRDDWriter.scala:58)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.EsSparkSQL$$anonfun$saveToEs$1.apply(EsSparkSQL.scala:94)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.EsSparkSQL$$anonfun$saveToEs$1.apply(EsSparkSQL.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopNoNodesLeftException: Connection error (check network and/or proxy settings)- all nodes failed; tried [[192.168.5.5:9200]]
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.NetworkClient.execute(NetworkClient.java:150)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:444)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:424)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:428)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.get(RestClient.java:154)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.remoteEsVersion(RestClient.java:609)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.InitializationUtils.discoverEsVersion(InitializationUtils.java:243)
        ... 10 more
17/04/26 15:29:03 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 7)
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Cannot detect ES version - typically this happens if the network/Elasticsearch cluster is not accessible or when targeting a WAN/Cloud instance without the proper setting 'es.nodes.wan.only'
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.InitializationUtils.discoverEsVersion(InitializationUtils.java:250)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestService.createWriter(RestService.java:546)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsRDDWriter.write(EsRDDWriter.scala:58)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.EsSparkSQL$$anonfun$saveToEs$1.apply(EsSparkSQL.scala:94)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.EsSparkSQL$$anonfun$saveToEs$1.apply(EsSparkSQL.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopNoNodesLeftException: Connection error (check network and/or proxy settings)- all nodes failed; tried [[192.168.5.5:9200]]
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.NetworkClient.execute(NetworkClient.java:150)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:444)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:424)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:428)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.get(RestClient.java:154)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.remoteEsVersion(RestClient.java:609)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.InitializationUtils.discoverEsVersion(InitializationUtils.java:243)
        ... 10 more
17/04/26 15:29:03 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 12
17/04/26 15:29:03 INFO Executor: Running task 0.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 12)
17/04/26 15:29:03 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 13
17/04/26 15:29:03 INFO TorrentBroadcast: Started reading broadcast variable 0
17/04/26 15:29:03 INFO Executor: Running task 0.1 in stage 2.0 (TID 13)
```

I want to extract the relevant lines so it looks like this:

```
17/04/26 15:29:03 ERROR NetworkClient: Node [192.168.5.5:9200] failed (Connection refused (Connection refused)); no other nodes left - aborting...
17/04/26 15:29:03 ERROR NetworkClient: Node [192.168.5.5:9200] failed (Connection refused (Connection refused)); no other nodes left - aborting...
17/04/26 15:29:03 ERROR NetworkClient: Node [192.168.5.5:9200] failed (Connection refused (Connection refused)); no other nodes left - aborting...
17/04/26 15:29:03 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 4)
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Cannot detect ES version - typically this happens if the network/Elasticsearch cluster is not accessible or when targeting a WAN/Cloud instance without the proper setting 'es.nodes.wan.only'
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.InitializationUtils.discoverEsVersion(InitializationUtils.java:250)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestService.createWriter(RestService.java:546)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsRDDWriter.write(EsRDDWriter.scala:58)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.EsSparkSQL$$anonfun$saveToEs$1.apply(EsSparkSQL.scala:94)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.EsSparkSQL$$anonfun$saveToEs$1.apply(EsSparkSQL.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopNoNodesLeftException: Connection error (check network and/or proxy settings)- all nodes failed; tried [[192.168.5.5:9200]]
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.NetworkClient.execute(NetworkClient.java:150)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:444)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:424)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:428)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.get(RestClient.java:154)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.remoteEsVersion(RestClient.java:609)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.InitializationUtils.discoverEsVersion(InitializationUtils.java:243)
        ... 10 more
17/04/26 15:29:03 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 6)
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Cannot detect ES version - typically this happens if the network/Elasticsearch cluster is not accessible or when targeting a WAN/Cloud instance without the proper setting 'es.nodes.wan.only'
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.InitializationUtils.discoverEsVersion(InitializationUtils.java:250)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestService.createWriter(RestService.java:546)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsRDDWriter.write(EsRDDWriter.scala:58)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.EsSparkSQL$$anonfun$saveToEs$1.apply(EsSparkSQL.scala:94)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.EsSparkSQL$$anonfun$saveToEs$1.apply(EsSparkSQL.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopNoNodesLeftException: Connection error (check network and/or proxy settings)- all nodes failed; tried [[192.168.5.5:9200]]
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.NetworkClient.execute(NetworkClient.java:150)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:444)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:424)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:428)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.get(RestClient.java:154)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.remoteEsVersion(RestClient.java:609)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.InitializationUtils.discoverEsVersion(InitializationUtils.java:243)
        ... 10 more
17/04/26 15:29:03 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 7)
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Cannot detect ES version - typically this happens if the network/Elasticsearch cluster is not accessible or when targeting a WAN/Cloud instance without the proper setting 'es.nodes.wan.only'
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.InitializationUtils.discoverEsVersion(InitializationUtils.java:250)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestService.createWriter(RestService.java:546)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsRDDWriter.write(EsRDDWriter.scala:58)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.EsSparkSQL$$anonfun$saveToEs$1.apply(EsSparkSQL.scala:94)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.EsSparkSQL$$anonfun$saveToEs$1.apply(EsSparkSQL.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopNoNodesLeftException: Connection error (check network and/or proxy settings)- all nodes failed; tried [[192.168.5.5:9200]]
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.NetworkClient.execute(NetworkClient.java:150)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:444)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:424)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:428)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.get(RestClient.java:154)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.remoteEsVersion(RestClient.java:609)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.InitializationUtils.discoverEsVersion(InitializationUtils.java:243)
        ... 10 more
```

How can I get the above output format (greping all ERROR lines with details)?

Answer (score 3):

It looks as if it should be enough to filter out the `INFO` messages from the input:

```
$ grep -v '[0-9] INFO ' file.in
```

I added `[0-9]` and the correct spacing around `INFO` just to be sure not to match any of the `ERROR`-related lines (in case a random string with `INFO` in it turns up there).

If you have a number of logfiles in a directory:

```
$ grep -v '[0-9] INFO ' *.log
```

where `*.log` is a filename pattern that matches the logfiles.

Comment: If i want to grep to a folder not a file then how can i grep? Because i want to check all files error and how i will grep only ERROR related data?

Comment: `grep -vR '[0-9] INFO ' /my/dir/location/*.log && man grep`

Answer (score 1):

I met exactly the same problem.

Though `grep` can show context lines by flag -A, but the amount of context lines is fixed. Instead, you could try `awk`.

Here is snippet which I have used before(https://gist.github.com/maoshuai/33113ac457aca7869171942c696f46d3), saved as fullgrep.sh:

```
full_grep()
{
    # keyword to search
    local keyword=$1
    # mark the actual new line, in this job, it is always a date
    local newLinePattern="^[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}"

    cat | awk  '
            BEGIN{
                isFound = "no"
            }

            # match lines with keyword
            {
                # if match print the line
                if($0~/'"$keyword"'/)
                {
                    print $0
                    isFound="yes"
                }
                # if new line begin, flush the flag
                else if($0~/'"$newLinePattern"'/) 
                {
                    isFound="no"
                }
                # if isFound, print continuely
                else if(isFound=="yes") 
                {
                    print $0
                }   
            }
            ' 
}


full_grep $@
```

Then type: `cat test.log| fullgrep.sh ERROR`, you should just get the desired output.